# Cucumber Page object PageObject.default_element_wait = 10 giving error

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I'm attempting to change the default element time out to 10 second by adding PageObject.default_element_wait = 10 to the env.rb page but I receive an error after saving.

The env.rb page

```
require 'rspec'
require 'page-object/page_factory'

PageObject.default_element_wait = 10
PageObject.default_page_wait = 10

World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

The error

```
Dimitris-MacBook-Pro:Cucumber_Automation dimitri$ cucumber features/element_validation.feature
undefined method `default_element_wait=' for PageObject:Module (NoMethodError)
/Users/dimitri/git/Cucumber_Automation/features/support/env.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong that's causing this to error out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It turns you need to require 'page-object' as well as 'page-object/page_factory'

```
require 'rspec'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
require 'page-object'

PageObject.default_element_wait=(10)


World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

Comment: Actually you only need to include page-object.